# Can i search Google Cloud Storage Bucket using metadata values?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am using metadata heavily with my Google Cloud Storage Bucket, now i have a use case where i need to search the files using some of the metadata field values. 
I have looked at the entire documentation (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WorkingWithObjectMetadata) but i didn't find anything related to search on Metadata, is there any why i can do this or should i go ahead and build something myself?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, GCS doesn't offer a search feature.

Comment: This is answer is invalid or probably outdated

Comment: This answer is still correct.

Answer (score 7):

**It is possible now to do so with APIs.**

**Set up CUSTOM metadata:**

- Visit [Viewing and Editing Object Metadata](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/viewing-editing-metadata#edit) documentation, for more information.
- Use `gsutil setmeta -h "[METADATA_KEY]:[METADATA_VALUE]" gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/[OBJECT_NAME]` command.
- [METADATA_KEY] should start with `x-goog-meta-` as stated in the documentation for custom metadata. So [METADATA_KEY] = `x-goog-meta-[CUSTOM_VALUE]`. NOTE no spaces in the value.
- [METADATA_VALUE] should also be without spaces. Use `_` or `-`.

**Search objects based on CUSTOM metadata of objects using APIs.**

This example is for Python, but there are a lot of other languages supported in the [Listing Objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects#storage-list-objects-python) documentation.

- List the objects in the bucket [Sample Code](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects#storage-list-objects-python)
- For every object found, list all the metadata. [Sample Code](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/viewing-editing-metadata#storage-view-object-metadata-python)
- Instead of printing them, take the `blob.metadata` part only and convert it to string. If it is a default value it will be `None` otherwise it will be your set up custom metadata key in JSON format.
- Use the value to perform a `==` operation to check if it is compatible with the value you are looking for and perform any actions accordingly.
- NOTE: The custom values are saved without the `x-goog-meta-` prefix. It is used only to determine for the API call when setting metadata that this value is custom. Only the second part will be visible in metadata. e.g. you use `x-goog-meta-test_metadata` it will be visible as `test_metadata`.

I have did a little bit of coding myself and this is a Python example doing exactly what I described above. You can find the [code in GitHub here](https://github.com/andrikosrikos/Google-Cloud-Support/blob/master/Bucket/search_objects_custom_metadata.py).

Comment: Author example in https://github.com/andrikosrikos/Google-Cloud-Support/blob/master/Bucket/search_objects_custom_metadata.py and documentation at https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects#storage-list-objects-python just confirms that search over metadata attributes is not supported. Example fetches all objects in the bucket and their metadata. It does not even attempts to show a client-side filtering of the result.

Comment: It may be better to configure your metadata in a Firestore collection together with associated Cloud Storage file names. This way you can use indexes to minimize search times.

Comment: This "solution" effectively _is_ client-side filtering, which means that ALL DATA must be fetched via the network, resulting in an insane amount of network activity, and as a result, a hefty GCS bill.